# How to Set properties to endpoint in Apache Camel using setters?

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel, dsl

I want to set some properties to the Endpoint as below.

from().to().setProperty(timeout,constant(12));

Using setProperty as above, it is setting property to the exchange/message object ?
How to retrieve this property in the endpoint itself or How to set it for endpoint (not by passing it in the URI ) ?

I know that we can pass this to the endpoint URI. But just want to know if there is a way to do with help of setters.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set properties to your from-endpoint you can do that like the following:

```
CxfEndpoint endpoint = (CxfEndpoint) new CxfComponent(this.getContext()).createEndpoint(<uri>);
endpoint.setxxx // here you can configure your endpoint with setters

from(endpoint)...
```

Comment: If you think the answer was helpfully, can you pls accept it?